# Migrate from Spring 2.5 Native ORM TopLink 10g to JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, eclipselink, toplink, spring-2.5

This may be annoying and discussed before but I could not find a good reference which would help to set a direction. I have to plan a migration of TopLink 10g (Spring 2.5 ORM Native Support) to JPA. I need some guidelines (steps) to follow and plan a successful migration.

Let me brief what I have in my technology stack. Primarily, as I mentioned above, application build around Spring 2.5 and Spring 2.5 Native ORM Support of TopLink. Spring 2.5 bundled to support only up to TopLink 10g and if you simply upgrade the TopLink JAR with the latest version it would not work as latest version of TopLink has completely changed the packaging but this still can be tackled by easily find and replace the package names. The main issue is the native api of TopLink ORM in Spring 2.5 which is built around TopLink 10g.

The reason of this migration activity is we cannot upgrade Spring until we migrate data-layer to JPA.

Please share steps if you already achieved something similar in your past or if the above briefing gives you an understanding on the problem you can also drop your opinion on how should I plan this migration.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar migration, toplink10g and Spring 2.5. For the integration we were using as support spring-toplink.jar, but not such support for toplink 12 that actually is the current version. At the moment seems it is not a straight fordward solution but I started first using the renaming tool provided by oracle.

The renaming tool it is necesary since jpa toplink 11 g is provided by eclipselink. You will see all the packages oracle.toplink.* will be renamed by org.eclipse.persistence.*

Did you have any advice othe advices for this migration?